# Media query ignored for one element but displayed for another

Tags: css, media-queries

I am using media queries to target 2 screen sizes:
1366px and smaller, and 1367px - 1920px.

Now below is my code.

**The problem** is that the #header element is being read fine by the browser, but for some reason the #footer element is displaying css rules for the **1366px query only**, even when the screen size is 1920 px...This is in Chrome and FF.

Why is this?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1920px) and (min-width: 1367px){
    #header{
        position: absolute;
        background: url('../images/back_1920_top.jpg') no-repeat left top;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 362px;
        width:100%;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #footer{
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        width:100%;
        height: 552px;
        background: url('../images/back_1920.jpg') no-repeat right bottom;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1366px){
    #header{
        position: absolute;
        background: url('../images/back_1280_top.jpg') no-repeat left top;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 245px;
        width:100%;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #footer{
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        width:100%;
        height: 300px;
        background: url('../images/back_1280.jpg') no-repeat right bottom;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
    }
}
```

[HERE](http://www.federalestene.co.za/) is a link to my site

NOTE: You will see the issue in the header and footer background image - The header background image on a 1920 screen is showing the **back_1920_top.jpg** image, but the footer is still showing the **back_1280.jpg** image...It is suppose to show the **back_1920.jpg** image...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your IE only stylesheet is overwriting your other styles, especially since it is at the bottom/below the other styles.

Do your CSS includes the right way: Use link tags:

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ie8.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<![endif]-->
```

I believe this will render much better